# "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" during inserting into table

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, parentheses

```
insert into eas_citizen_text_info
    values(690102355714,'male','Shailendra','Baliram','Torane',('1995-06-02','yyyy-mm-dd'),21,'Bauddha','Single','Building no-E9, Room no-23, Rajarshi Shahu Nagar,Mahim(East),Mumbai-17','Buildin no-E9, Room no-23','Rajarshi Shahu Nagar','Shahu Nagar Police Station','Mahim','Mumbai','Shahu Nagar','Mumbai',null,400017,'Maharashtra','Baliram Shankar Torane','Sandhya Baliram Torane',null,'shailendra123456789'
    )
```

Comment: Date function missing?

Comment: m using date datatype, so i hv entered value directly, isn't tat allowed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
('1995-06-02','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

should be

```
TO_DATE('1995-06-02','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

You are not entering a date, you are entering a `VARCHAR2` enclosed in parentheses which Oracle doesn't seem to handle.

The `VARCHAR2` alone might work and get implicitly converted to `DATE` if your session is configured correctly. 
It is better to not rely on this kind of configuration and do the conversion explicitly using the `TO_DATE` function.

Comment: changing the datatype from "date" to "to_date" will work??